# Нужна ли запятая? Как это объяснить?

Tags: пунктуация

Ты видел (,) чем они поливали свинью?

Как мне кажется, запятая нужна, ибо это СПП. Но мой друг считает иначе.

Answer (score 2):

Это действительно СПП. Здесь дополнение выражено изъяснительным придаточным предложением (от главного слова ставится вопрос косвенного падежа).
Более того, если вы не поставите запятую, сразу возникнет двусмысленность: «ты видел чем...» (глазами!). Запятая однозначно нужна.